# Search data from database according to given data using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to retrieving data from database according to my given data in search field using SQL server.I am explaining the scenario below. Suppose I have this table in my database:

`T_hospital_Clinic`:

```
ID     Hospital        Clinic           Location        department
------------------------------------------------------------------
1      KIIMS Hosp.     Kar clinic       Bhubaneswar     Pediatric.
2      SCB medical     Aswani clinic    Cuttack         ENT
3      Sum             Mishra clinic    Bhubaneswar     Orthopedic
4      AMRI            Image dignisys   Cuttack         Neorolgy
5      AIIMS           Mahaveer clinic  Bhubaneswar     ENT
6      shree Hosp      shaoo's clinic   Cuttack        pediatric.
```

Here the table name is `T_hospital_Clinic` and I need by putting any location / department name inside search field, I can access the hospital / clinic name.

Suppose I want to check how many hospital / clinics are present in Bhubaneswar those are belongs `ENT` department and in this case what should be the SQL query to find out the data.

Please help me to write the proper query to solve this problem.

Comment: Look at how to use  " like"  in sql,or if you are serach by full name insted of any shortforms or words then just use =, example select Hospital,Clinic         from T_hospital_Clinic  where Location        ='Bhubaneswar ' and department='ENT',or if you want the total number of results then use count() function

Comment: and also mysql,and sql server are different so which one you want ??

Comment: I need this in SQL server.

Comment: you want total count ?? or Hospital /Clinic names based on search criteria???

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV: What i need actually when user will put data in search field as i explained above the total hospital/clinic name belongs to that data only  will featch.

Comment: What exactly is the input? what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Zohar : Please take a look to my table given in post.Suppose i entered `Bhubaneswar'  in one search field  and  `ENT`  in another search field when i will click on search button i want to fetch all hospital/clinic name according to that search data.Here i need only SQL query to retieving the data .

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a very basic sql statement with a `where` clause that contains 2 conditions on 2 columns joined by an `and`:

```
SELECT Hospital, Clinic
FROM T_hospital_Clinic
WHERE Location = @Location -- perhaps it's better to use LIKE here instead
AND department = @department
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the process is starting from your ui, you have to featch the seach values from the search box in ui and pass that values as a parameter to 
a stored procedure and call the stored procedure from your server side code then inside stored procedure write a query to get the details and then display and reload the details with the newly get details.

stored procedure is like

```
   IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM sys.objects
        WHERE NAME = 'exampleproc' type = 'P'
        )
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE exampleproc
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE exampleproc @Location NVARCHAR(1000);

@department NVARCHAR(1000);AS

BEGIN
    SELECT Hospital
        ,Clinic
    FROM T_hospital_Clinic
    WHERE Location = @Location
        AND department = @department
END
```

Comment: @satya ok try and let me know if you have any doubts

Comment: Downvote reasons: **1st.** there is no need for a transaction if it only contains a single statement. **2nd.** if you have a transaction and commit it in the try block, you need to rollback in the catch clause.

Comment: @ZoharPeled i have changed it based on your comment..thanks for correcting me

Comment: @ZoharPeled i have a doubt, is it necessary to rollback in catch clause if the try only contain the  select operation ??

Comment: doesn't matter, if you have an open transaction it needs to be closed either by commit or by rollback...

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
Select Hospital
      ,Clinic
FROM T_hospital_Clinic
WHERE Location = 'Fill empty string with Hospital Location'
AND department = 'Fill empty string with Department Name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to show clinics/hospitals that belongs to a location / department starts with text entered by the user or contains it? Case sensitive/ Case insensitive?

Case sensitive:

For starts case:

```
SELECT Hospital, Clinic
FROM T_hospital_Clinic
WHERE Location LIKE @location + '%' 
AND department LIKE @department + '%'
```

For contains case:

```
SELECT Hospital, Clinic
FROM T_hospital_Clinic
WHERE Location LIKE '%' + @location + '%' 
AND department LIKE '%' + @department  + '%'
```

Case insensitive:

For starts case:

```
SELECT Hospital, Clinic
FROM T_hospital_Clinic
WHERE LOWER(Location) LIKE LOWER(@location) + '%' 
AND LOWER(department) LIKE LOWER(@department) + '%'
```

For contains case:

```
SELECT Hospital, Clinic
FROM T_hospital_Clinic
WHERE LOWER(Location) LIKE '%' + LOWER(@location) + '%' 
AND LOWER(department) LIKE '%' + LOWER(@department)  + '%'
```

Where @location and  @department exact text entered by user into search fields Department and Location

If it is not a huge amount of data I suggest to return all data from table on client side and then filter them there - it will be faster and reduce load on database